# Is it possible to express the Lorentz force in terms of differential forms?

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, forces, tensor-calculus

The electromagentism can be formulated in terms of differential forms, defining de electromagnetic four-potential $A$ as a 1-form, the electromagnetic 2-form (to give it a name) $F=dA$, etc. And the Lorentz force is defined as the inner product of the electromagentic tensor, which is the 2-form as a 2-rank tensor (I think you understand what I'm trying to say with that), with the four-velocity(and the charge), but it can be defined directly like some operation using the 2-form $F$ and the four-velocity?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A $p$-form is, in tensor terms, a tensor whose components have exactly $p$ lower indices that are antisymmetric. For example, the electromagnetic 2-form $F=dA$ can be written in terms of its components as follows:

$$F_{\mu\nu} = \partial_\mu A_\nu - \partial_\nu A_\mu.$$

Meanwhile, a vector is, in tensor terms, a tensor whose components have exactly one upper index. For example, the relativistic 4-velocity has components $u^\mu$.

There is a way to take the product of a vector and a $p$-form and get a $p-1$-form from it; it's called the [interior product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interior_product). The equations on the Wikipedia page may look formidable, but in terms of the components, you simply contract the (upper) vector index with the first (lower) index of the $p$-form:

$$(\iota_u F)_\nu = u^\mu F_{\mu\nu},$$

where $\iota_u F$ denotes the interior product of the vector $u$ with the 2-form $F$, and $(\iota_u F)_\nu$ are the components of the resulting 1-form. (Note that if you contract one index of a $p$-form you will have $p-1$ lower antisymmetric indices left, and that's why the interior product takes $p$-forms to $p-1$-forms.)

Using the interior product, we can now very easily write down the force 1-form $f$ as the interior product of the 4-velocity $u$ with the electromagnetic 2-form $F$, times the electric charge $q$:

$$f = q \, \iota_u F,$$

or in terms of components,

$$f_\nu = q \, u^\mu F_{\mu\nu}.$$

Note: Sometimes you will see the interior product written as $\iota_u F = u \lrcorner F$. In this notation, the Lorentz force is $f = q \, u \lrcorner F$.

Further reading: Geometry, Topology And Physics, 2nd Edition, by Nakahara.